# Create multiple groups from lists

Tags: ansible

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  vars:
    user_details:
      - name: 'testuser1'
        groups: ['sysadmin', 'sa-deploy']

      - name: 'testuser2'
        groups: ['sa-deploy']

      - name: 'testuser3'
        groups: ['sa-deploy']

      - name: 'testuser4'
        groups: ['sa-deploy','systemd-oom']

  tasks:
    - name: Manage groups
      group:
        name: "{{item.groups}}"
        state: present
      loop:
         - "{{ user_details }}"
```

I'm trying to figure out how to parse the list values of groups for each user, but the task above is failing.

The whole idea is that I'm trying to create multiple groups for users, if not already present.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) in order to extract all the `groups` attributes:

   ```yaml
   - debug:
       var: user_details | map(attribute='groups')
   ```

   Gives:

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     user_details | map(attribute='groups'):
     - - sysadmin 
       - sa-deploy
     - - sa-deploy
     - - sa-deploy
     - - sa-deploy
       - systemd-oom
   ```
2. [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html) the resulting list of lists

   ```yaml
   - debug:
       var: user_details | map(attribute='groups') | flatten
   ```

   Gives:

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     user_details | map(attribute='groups') | flatten:
     - sysadmin
     - sa-deploy
     - sa-deploy
     - sa-deploy
     - sa-deploy
     - systemd-oom
   ```
3. Tidy up the list and make it [`unique`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.unique), so you don't loop multiple times on the same group:

   ```yaml
   - debug:
       var: user_details | map(attribute='groups') | flatten | unique
   ```

   Gives:

   ```yaml
   ok: [localhost] => 
     user_details | map(attribute='groups') | flatten | unique:
     - sysadmin
     - sa-deploy
     - systemd-oom
   ```
4. Use the resulting list in you loop:

   ```yaml
   - group:
       name: "{{ item }}"
     loop: "{{ user_details | map(attribute='groups') | flatten | unique }}"
   ```

   Gives:

   ```yaml
   changed: [localhost] => (item=sysadmin) => changed=true 
     ansible_loop_var: item
     gid: 1000
     item: sysadmin
     name: sysadmin
     state: present
     system: false
   changed: [localhost] => (item=sa-deploy) => changed=true 
     ansible_loop_var: item
     gid: 1001
     item: sa-deploy
     name: sa-deploy
     state: present
     system: false
   changed: [localhost] => (item=systemd-oom) => changed=true 
     ansible_loop_var: item
     gid: 1002
     item: systemd-oom
     name: systemd-oom
     state: present
     system: false
   ```

   *<sup>Note: the above output was generated running the playbook with the option `-v`, which, amongst other useful information, shows the result of the actions done by the `group` task.</sup>*